# How to apply coding standards to a project automatically?

Tags: c, code-analysis, software

I have a large project. The project has many non-conforming lines according to coding standard that I used. Is there a tool, AI or anything that can make the process faster  than doing by hand. I am not comfortable to copy and past the code to AI directly from the security perspective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having a coding style does not need AI. This problem has been solved for years using rules.

[ClangFormat](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormat.html) can help you format your C code, i.e. change indentation, braces, newlines, spacing etc.

[ClangTidy](https://clang.llvm.org/extra/clang-tidy/) goes one step further and performs diagnostics on your code, i.e. checks for unreachable code, overflows and other stuff, which is not related to syntax only, but also semantics.

Both products are side-products of the clang compiler and AFAIK, they use the clang compiler to produce the AST (abstract syntax tree) and then do their analysis on the tree. Since clang is a major known compiler, both tools are also of good quality.